# trying to understand a particular scenario in responsive design

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Let's say I have a div on a webpage that displays on a desktop at 1000px width.  Let's say I want that div to display at 100% width in portrait mode on all phones.  What would be the easiest way to accomplish this without using Bootstrap?

Comment: You can't force the device to display at 1000px wide. Is it important for the div to be exactly that width? Why not use `width: 100%`?

Comment: Do you know what size phone screens are? http://mydevice.io/devices/ Many aren't 1000px wide.

Answer (score 1):

```
.yourdiv {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
}
```

This rule would work pretty well in situations like these: It makes the DIV 1000px wide if the screen is wider than 1000px, and makes it 100% wide on all screens which are less than 1000px wide.

Answer (score 0):

Johannes answer is really awesome but if you need to have more control over what's displayed, you can always use media queries.

Example: hiding a sidebar only when the screen width is <= 600px:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .sidebar {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

You can find out more here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries